# Variable list automatically updated in python

Tags: python, list

I play with python 2.7. Here's my problem:

```
>>> bra=[]
>>> put=['a','t']
>>> bra.append(put)
>>> bra
[['a', 't']]
>>> bra.append(put)
>>> bra
[['a', 't'], ['a', 't']]
>>> bra.append(put.reverse())
>>> bra
[['t', 'a'], ['t', 'a'], None]
```

My question is: why does de python interpreter give that result in the last line, instead this:

```
[['a', 't'], ['a', 't'], ['t', 'a']]
```

or how can I get this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.reverse()` modifies the list in-place, and doesn't return anything, which is equivalent to returning `None`.

You need `reversed(put)`. [This function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) indeed returns an inversed version of the iterable.

Answer (score 5):

Two issues:

1. The `list.reverse` method modifies the list in-place and doesn't return anything (i.e. it returns `None`).  You probably wanted to use the [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) method instead.
2. Both of the first two elements in your `bra` list refer to the same underlying object.  So, when you modified that object, both of the first two elements again referred to that same modified object, so that's why you see `['t', 'a']` for both of the first two elements.

If you want to use separate objects instead of references to the same object, you can make copies by using the slicing operator:

```
bra.append(put[:])  # Appends a copy of 'put'
```

As an alternative to the `reversed` method, you can also use the slicing operator with a step of -1 to reverse an iterable, although to some people, it's not as obvious what the code is doing:

```
bra.append(put[::-1])  # Equivalent to bra.append(reversed(put))
```

Comment: +1 for explaining why `bra[0]` and `bra[1]` got reversed, as well as why `bra[2]` was `None`.